# Why hidden file can't be open in create and write mode in MFC？

Tags: c++, mfc

I am using Visual C++ 2010 & MFC to write a small program.

Following is my code:

```
        CFile MyFile;
        CFileException* pException = NULL;
        CString strErrorMessage;
        //  The Test.txt is a hidden file that I created already.
        if (!MyFile.Open(_T("E:\\Test.txt"), CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate, pException))
        {
            TCHAR lpCause[255];
            pException->GetErrorMessage(lpCause, 255);
            strErrorMessage += lpCause;
        }
        //  ...
        //  rewrite the Test.txt
        //  ...
        MyFile.Close();
```

So Following are my questions:

1.When running the code, unhandled exception comes out.So how can I modify my code to make it work?

2.I try to remove Test.txt hidden file attribute, it seems to work well.I wanna know: why a file(that is existed) with file hidden attribute can't be open in create and write mode?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pException` is only initialized to `NULL`, it is not allocated. You should allocate it, or simply declare `CFileException exception;` and pass the address `&exception`. Also, don't attempt to close the file if `CFile::Open` failed.

Documentation for [CFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60fh2b6f.aspx#cfile__cfile) says not to use `CFile::modeCreate` for existing files because it raises an exception. The reasoning is not exactly right.

In Visual Studio 15, MFC's source code for `CFile::Open` shows:

```
// map creation flags
if (nOpenFlags & modeCreate)
{
    if (nOpenFlags & modeNoTruncate)
        dwCreateFlag = OPEN_ALWAYS;
    else
        dwCreateFlag = CREATE_ALWAYS;
}
else
    dwCreateFlag = OPEN_EXISTING;
...
CreateFile(... nOpenFlags ...)
```

`CFile::modeCreate` (without `modeNoTruncate`) sets the flag `CREATE_ALWAYS` in `CreateFile` API. WinAPI documentation for [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) says

> If `CREATE_ALWAYS` and `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL` are specified, `CreateFile`
>   fails and sets the last error to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` if the file
>   exists and has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN` or `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM`
>   attribute. To avoid the error, specify the same attributes as the
>   existing file.

That explains why the function fails only for files which are existing and hidden.

To fix this, we can add `modeNoTruncate` to force `OPEN_ALWAYS`. Use `CFile::SetLength(0)` to truncate the file if required.

```
CFile MyFile;
CFileException exception;
CString strErrorMessage;
CString filename = _T("e:\\Test.txt");

if(MyFile.Open(filename, CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate, 
    &exception))
{
    //SetLength(0) if file needs to truncate
    MyFile.SetLength(0);
    MyFile.Close();
}
else
{
    TCHAR lpCause[255];
    exception.GetErrorMessage(lpCause, 255);
    strErrorMessage += lpCause;
}
```

Alternatively, test for existence of old file, add `CFile::modeCreate` if file does not exists. Again followed by `SetLength(0)` to truncate the file.

```
UINT flags = CFile::modeWrite;
if(!PathFileExists(filename))
    flags |= CFile::modeCreate;
if (MyFile.Open(filename, flags, &exception))
{
    MyFile.SetLength(0);
    MyFile.Close();
}
```

Comment: Maybe also add that the help provided clearly explains this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270518(v=vs.60).aspx “A pointer to an existing file-exception object that will receive the status of a failed operation.”. It even has an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I modify my code, and I get the CFileException error message:"Access deny to E:\Test.txt". So I think hidden file attribute is the cause.

Comment: Yes,I am on Windows 10.So is there a good way to rewrite a existed file absolutely? Do I have to delete the existed file and create a new file again?

Comment: I learn fopen function in C opening a file in 'w' mode,it will discard the existed file contents, and do writing.But is there a way to do the same thing by MFC?

Comment: Use `GetFileAttributes` to see if file is there, as shown in edit. MFC documentation could be partly wrong. I'll check this later on Windows 7.

Comment: Ps, you can use `MyFile.SetLength(0);` to delete all the old content.

Comment: I use `PathFileExists` to test for existence.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Thanks, I edited per your suggestion.

Comment: The test for existence is obsolete, simply specify `CFile::modeWrite | CFile::modeCreate | CFile::modeNoTruncate`. This translates into `OPEN_ALWAYS` flag for `CreateFile` which doesn't fail if the file already exists (regardless of hidden or system attributes).

Comment: @zett42 Thanks, I changed the answer again per you suggestion.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks,I get it.